# Save value of the variable

Tags: ios7, nsuserdefaults

Here is the `NSUserdefaults` code.

```
-(IBAction)SaveButton:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* Assignment0Text = screen0.text;
    [defaults setObject:Assignment0Text forKey:@"Assignment0Text"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(IBAction)LoadButton:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSString* temp0 = [defaults objectForKey:@"Assignment0Text"];
    screen0.text = temp0;

}
```

This code above means that the program only saves and loads the string value inside the textfield/label.

My question is, how can I modify this code so that the `NSUserDefaults` can save and load the value of a variable (in this case int & float), not the text inside the textfield/label? So that when I load the program, all the integer/float values are the same. Not what's written in the text inside the textfield/label are the same. All that the screen is showing is a float number with variable called `runningtotal`.

```
screen0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%2.2f", runningtotal];
```

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, you should use wrappers for variables like `int`:

`int value = 5;
[defaults setObject:@(value) forKey:@"Assignment0Number"];`

the magic is the `NSUserDefaults` can not store non-object values like `5`. You need to create `NSObject` object, store the value within it, and then save this object into the `NSUserdefaults`. That is what happens when I write '@(value)'.

If to be more precise, `@(value)` is literal for `[NSNumber numberWithInt:value]`, and since `NSNumber` is the object and subclass of `NSObject`, the value can be stored now.

EDIT:

here is what you probably want (I assume that `runningtotal` is the class variable):

```
-(IBAction)SaveButton:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [defaults setObject:@(runningtotal) forKey:@"Assignment0Text"];
    [defaults synchronize];
}

-(IBAction)LoadButton:(id)sender {

    NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    NSNumber* temp0 = [defaults objectForKey:@"Assignment0Text"];
    runningtotal = [temp0 intValue];

}
```

Comment: Thank You. so it suppose to be like this?

-(IBAction)SaveButton:(id)sender {
    NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    
    NSString* Assignment0Text = screen0.text;
    [defaults setObject:[NSNumber numberWithInt:runningtotal] forKey:@"Assignment0Number"];
    
    NSString* Assignment1Text = screen1.text;
    [defaults setObject:@(runningtotal) forKey:@"Assignment1Text"];